# insert date with time in access database c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

In the access I'm only getting the date  `5/12/2015` but no the time, I need something like this

`5/12/2015 4:56 PM` saved in the access database

```
  DateTime dtclickdate = DateTime.Now;
  OleDbParameter clickdate = new OleDbParameter("@clickdate ", OleDbType.DBDate);
  clickdate.Value = dtclickdate; 
  cmd.Parameters.Add(clickdate);
```

Comment: Label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

that give me  the date + time, but for some reason in access doesn't work, maybe I have to to something in the access database

In formart in access I have "General Date"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [the MSDN description of OleDbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **DBDate**:     Date data in the format yyyymmdd (DBTYPE_DBDATE). This maps to DateTime.

As you can see, `DBDate` does not contain a time component. I would suggest to use `Date` instead:

> **Date**:   Date data, stored as a double (DBTYPE_DATE). The whole portion is the number of days since December 30, 1899, and the fractional portion is a fraction of a day. This maps to DateTime.

According to the following Microsoft Knowledge Base article, this is the correct type to use for Access Date/Time fields.

Quoted from [INFO: OleDbType Enumeration vs. Microsoft Access Data Types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320435):

```
Access Type Name  Database Data Type  OLE DB Type  .NET Framework Type  Member Name
    ...
Date/Time         DateTime            DBTYPE_DATE  System.DateTime    OleDbType.Date
    ...
```

<sub>*StackOverflow should really [add support for tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/138661)...*</sub>

PS: Note that [OLEDB does not like Milliseconds in Date/Time fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6253906). If you get a *Data type mismatch in criteria expression* error, remove the milliseconds:

```
dtm = New DateTime(dtm.Year, dtm.Month, dtm.Day, dtm.Hour, dtm.Minute, dtm.Second)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `OleDbType.DBTimeStamp` enumeration, which maps to `DateTime`:

```
DateTime dtclickdate = DateTime.Now;
OleDbParameter clickdate = new OleDbParameter("@clickdate ", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp);
clickdate.Value = dtclickdate; cmd.Parameters.Add(clickdate);
```

See [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try `OleDbType.DBTimeStamp`:

```
DateTime dtclickdate = DateTime.Now;
OleDbParameter clickdate = new OleDbParameter("@clickdate ", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp);
clickdate.Value = dtclickdate; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(clickdate);
```

Reason: this also stores time fraction as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: getting this Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression,

I'm trying to figure why

Comment: Just a guess: can you try: clickdate.Value = dtclickdate.ToString();

Comment: @Yan: That's because Access does not like Milliseconds. Remove them first: `dtm = New DateTime(dtm.Year, dtm.Month, dtm.Day, dtm.Hour, dtm.Minute, dtm.Second)`

Comment: you are genius =D @Heinzi


DateTime dtclickdate;

                DateTime dtm=DateTime.Now;


            

          

            dtm = new DateTime(dtm.Year, dtm.Month, dtm.Day, dtm.Hour, dtm.Minute, dtm.Second);


            dtclickdate = dtm;