# What is the best way to get rid of milliseconds from DateTime?

Tags: c#

When I get DateTime from the database, it returns
`2021-06-23T12:30:40.1234564z` but what I want is `2021-06-23T12:30:40z`. What is the best way to get rid of the milliseconds here? Thanks.

Comment: use a formatter withoput milliseconds

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: That will return a string, not modify the original DateTime. I have needed the latter in the past a few times (for example, when comparing a value with a value stored somewhere where milliseconds are lost: the WebForms ViewState or certain database systems). Or [this OLEDB bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6253906/87698).

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I use this:

```
dt = dt.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, dt.Millisecond));
```

It's a little more verbose than the Ticks-Modulo-Trickery that can be used instead, but I like its readability: It's immediately obvious what the code does.

---

As JonSkeet suggested in the comments, this is more compact and equally readable:

```
dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(-dt.Millisecond);
```

I like it even better than my solution, since in my solution a hard-to-spot bug can easily be introduced by forgetting one of the `0` parameters.

Comment: Slightly simpler: `dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(-dt.Millisecond)`

Comment: @JonSkeet: Good point. Since you didn't write your own, I've taken the liberty to add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, date.Second, date.Kind);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer by @jonskeet you could also round

```
if(dt.millis>500) dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(1000)
dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(-dt.millis);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2021 - 06 - 23T12: 30:40z");

var ss = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: This lacks the "T" in the middle and the "Z" at the end, and "hh" is 12-hour time, whereas "HH" is 24-hour time. Also, you might want to call `.ToUniversalTime()` before calling `.ToString(...)` to ensure that it actually is universal time before you format it.

Comment: @Llama Thanks for the suggestion. Based on your suggestion and my code user can decide. Happy Coding.

Comment: Okay, but your "suggestion" isn't what the OP asked for. OP said: _"but what I want is 2021-06-23T12:30:40z."_ - does your solution produce this format?

Answer (score -1):

dt.ToString("YYYYY/MM/DD");

Comment: `YYYY` and `DD` don't exist in .NET for formatting datetime values, and even if they did, this lacks the hours, minutes, and seconds.